# Selecting all with related products

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `teachings`:

`id`,`name`,`description`

And a `products` table:
`id`,`name`,`description`,`teachingID`

I want to select all from teachings that have products associated to them.  If there is a teaching that has no products in the products table, I don't want it.

So far I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM `teachings`
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`teachingID` = `teachings`.`id`
WHERE COUNT(`products`) > 0
```

But that doesn't work :(  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So why use a LEFT JOIN then !?!?!?!?!?!!?

Comment: I prefer INNER Join for this

Comment: @Strawberry I always use left join for all my joins and it's never let me down until now! :P

Comment: It seems to me you should use the right tool for the job. And I'm puzzled at your choice of accepted answer. (Performance issues aside) The correct solution in this instance is definitely an INNER JOIN, as per my answer below. Note that the INNER keyword is optional, and frequently omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only to return teachings with at least one product associated with it then use `exists` subquery. This way you do not have to count products per teaching.

My `mysql` got rusty but this should do

```
select *
from teachings t
where exists
(
   select 1
   from products p
   where p.teachingID = t.id
)
```

Comment: This is the straight-forward way. And you can even use an `IN` clause instead of the `EXISTS` clause which would make the query still simpler and more readable.

Comment: @Chud37 But why opt for such an elaborate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional answer simply to show the IN clause I was talking of in a comment. The task is very simple: Get teachings records for which **exist** a product record. In other words: Get teachings records that are mentioned **in** the products table. So one uses `EXISTS` or `IN` here.

To join the tables only obfuscates what is being done, so don't do that.

The `EXISTS` query:

```
select *
from teachings t
where exists (select * from products p where p.teachingid = t.id);
```

The `IN` query, which is even more readable, because the subquery is not correlated to the main query:

```
select *
from teachings t
where id in (select teachingid from products p);
```

Comment: You are right, that is more readable.  I've already marked an answer as correct but thank you I like the second SQL you've got there.